# Passing a NSInteger to a size_t and a NSInteger* to a size_t*

Tags: c++, objective-c

My C++ knowledge stinks. I have a code provided by Apple where they, as usually, provided an incomplete solution.

On this code they provide two empty methods headers:

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
```

These methods, in theory, should call two C++ style functions, but as my C++ knowledge stinks infinity squared plus one, please fill the ???

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
   // I need to call base64_encode and return its results as string... is this correct?

   return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
       base64_encode(input, ???)];
    // ??? I need to pass a NSInteger to a size_t... how do I do that?
}


- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{

// ??? = this method receives a NSInteger *length variable. How do I pass that
// to a size_t * variable required by base64_decode?

    NSString *st = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:
                    base64_decode([input UTF8String], ???)
                                            length:&length
                                          encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return st;
}
```

these 2 methods call these C++ functions

```
char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{
   // bla bla bla
}

void* base64_decode(const char* s, size_t* data_len_ptr)
{
    // bla bla bla
}
```

thanks.

Comment: `length:&length` should probably be `length:*length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to do base64 encode/decode you will find it easier to start with a properly worked out example for how to do so. Matt Gallagher gives easy recipes for doing this in [Base64 encoding options on the Mac and iPhone](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html).

If you really want to flesh out your example, keep in mind that `NSInteger` is a `long` and `size_t` is an `unsigned long`. You could replace the lines in question with the following:

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:base64_encode(input, (size_t)length)];
}

- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{
    size_t retLen;
    uint8_t *retStr = base64_decode([input UTF8String], &retLen);
    if (length)
        *length = (NSInteger)retLen;
    NSString *st = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:retStr
                                        length:retLen
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    free(retStr);    // If base64_decode returns dynamically allocated memory
    return st;
}
```

(Remove the autorelease if you are compiling under ARC.)

Note that an arbitrary sequence of bytes is not guaranteed to be a valid UTF-8 string. This API allows you to send in arbitrary bytes but assumes it will decode to a valid UTF-8 string, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: `initWithBytes` takes an `NSUInteger` value for `length` parameter, not a pointer. Also, `retStr` most likely points to a dynamically allocated block of memory, which should be freed after converting into `NSString`. And `autorelease` is not used under ARC.

Comment: @RubberDuck There is at least one error and a memory leak in the answer you accepted. Jus' lettin' you kno.

Comment: Xcode is complaining "incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to NSinteger * from NSInteger on the length = ... line and another error on the line after that (incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending size_t* to parameter of type NSUinteger... and it is pointing to &retLen. Your retLen is empty when you call base64_decode... is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for corrections @RubberDuck. I edited the code. As he mentions you don't need autorelease if you are compiling under ARC, but do otherwise.

Comment: @torrey.lyons, you have not changed the two lines with error that I have mentioned. The errors persist. Please read my comment.

Comment: You can see exactly what I changed clicking the [edited link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11638415/revisions). I changed `length = (NSInteger)retLen` to `*length = (NSInteger)retLen` and `length:&retLen` to `length:retLen`. I tested in the compiler and this compiles without errors. My `retLen` is empty when `base64_decode` is called since I assumed this function would get the input length from the string itself. If this is not how your function works you would just have to change the first line to `size_t retLen = [input length]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `NSInteger` is some integral type, and assuming `ln` is a variable (or argument) of that type you can cast it to `size_t` by coding `(size_t)ln` or (C++ only) `size_t(ln)` or `static_cast<size_t>(ln)`

For a pointer `p` to [an array of] `NSInteger`-s, casting `NSInteger*` to `size_t*` might not make sense (or at least give strange effects) if they don't have the same size (as given by `sizeof`). If you still want that consider coding `reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(p)` but try `static_cast<size_t*>(p)` at first.

Please understand what all this is doing, you could have bad surprises or undefined behavior (e.g. when going from 32 bits to 64 bits processors, or from big-endian to little-endian ones).

Comment: `NSInteger` is Apple's `typedef` for a 64-bit `int`. (Well, sometimes it's 32.)

Comment: I did guess it was an integral type, hence I assumed it. Perhaps it is more an `intptr_t` because Apple might cast it to pointers sometimes????